# load URL into WebBrowser with MVVM

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I'm makeing an app where you have a listbox in the buttom with a logo of different websites, and a `WebBrowser`on the top. The idea is that when you press on a logo, the webBrowser load the corresponding page. I already make this work, but I want to remake the app with MVVM to make it better. I've made the listbox with all the logos, but I dont know how to load the URL onto the `WebBrowser` when I click on the logo.

Answer (score 7):

Not 100% sure if this will work on Phone7 but worth a shot...

Fist off the `WebBrowser` Source property is not bindable as its not a `DependancyProperty` so you will have to make a helper class to create an `AttachedProperty` to help with the binding.

Then you can link your `ListBox` `SelectedItem` to the new `LinkSource` property using the Property that contains the actual link from your ListBoxItem.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="405" Name="UI">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Links}" Width="100" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <WebBrowser local:WebBrowserHelper.LinkSource="{Binding ElementName=listbox, Path=SelectedItem.Site}" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Link> _links = new ObservableCollection<Link>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Links.Add(new Link { Name = "StackOverflow", Site = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/") });
        Links.Add(new Link { Name = "Google", Site = new Uri("http://www.google.com/") });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Link> Links
    {
        get { return _links; }
        set { _links = value; }
    }
}

// ListBox item
public class Link
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Site { get; set; }
}


// helper calss to create AttachedProperty
public static class WebBrowserHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LinkSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LinkSource", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, LinkSourcePropertyChanged));

    public static string GetLinkSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(LinkSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLinkSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LinkSourceProperty, value);
    }

    // When link changed navigate to site.
    public static void LinkSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser != null)
        {
            string uri = e.NewValue as string;
            browser.Source = uri != null ? new Uri(uri) : null;
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Even if this doesn't work on windows phone, this shows how to use DP better than some other tutorials I've read - to the point I now see why they exist, and how I could use them in a RichTextBox.

Answer (score -1):

Your question are actually two questions.

1. There're several ways to pick up clicks from listbox. Most basic one is `<Listbox SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem,mode=TwoWay}" ...`
2. To set the web browser's URL, you could implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM, declare `public Uri browserUri { get; private set; }` in your WM, be sure to raise PropertyChanged when you change the property, and in XAML `<WebBrowser Source="{Binding browserUri}" />`

Comment: XAML exception:  A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'WebBrowser'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: This does not work. Exception "XAML exception: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'WebBrowser'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."